# CSS Transition property not working

Tags: css

I'm having a problem with the css transition property, can anyone help me out?

HTML:

```
<div>HOVER ME
    <div class="slide">aaa <br />
         aaa <br />
        aaa <br />
        aaa <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slide {
    height: 0px;
    visibility: hidden;
    width:100px;
    background-color: blue;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s ease;
    transition: height 2s ease;
}

div:hover > .slide {
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLEGYr

Comment: Transitions with the `display` property changing will never work. Use `visibility` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```css
.slide {

  max-height: 0;
  width:100px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

div:hover > .slide {
  max-height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>HOVER ME
<div class="slide">aaa <br />
  aaa <br />
  aaa <br />
  aaa <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bqef5kpm/1/

Answer (score 2):

Like stated, it won't work with display property. Furthermore, animation with height: auto won't work too. A display less and height:auto less version below.

```
.slide {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.2s;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}

*:hover > .slide {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 0.2s;
}
```